# Can 2 wires of a higher gauge be used in place of 1 wire with a lower gauge?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I need to wire a 220v 55 amp circuit in the attic for a new HVAC system.  I would normally run a single 6 gauge wire to handle the 55 amps.  However, I already have 2 10 gauge wires run to the attic.  Can I connect the 2 10 gauge wires together at both the MSP and the box in the attic and protect it with a 55 amp breaker and have it function the same way as a single 6 gauge wire?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot parallel that size conductor. Rule 12-108 states that conductors smaller than 1/0 AWG cu or al cannot be paralleled. You will need to run the larger wire.

Comment: Is that a CEC reference, perchance? (The NEC ref for this would be 310.10(H), BTW)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Yes, and I don't know why I thought he was from Canada.... mixed up with another qustion.

Comment: What is the reason? If the connections are reliable and if the sum of the cross sections is the same, physically it should be even a better solution, since the cooling surface is much bigger and the mechanical stress should be smaller where the cables are bended.

Comment: @xeeka: legalese about code. they have to cater for lowest common denomators, so even though it would be measurably better, it's not allowed, probably because if half breaks, all the load is on one over-rated wire, whereas when one wire breaks the load is zero.

Comment: @dandavis The famous nail or screw run into the wall or ceiling could also decrease the cross section of a single bigger wire. Wouldn't that be the same overrated wire situation?

Comment: @xeeka -- also keep in mind that if the two wires are different lengths, the shorter wire will tend to "hog" the current...(Code requires lengths to match even when you are allowed to parallel, but there's a certain degree of tolerance required in order to account for practical limitations)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The shorter one has the slightly lower resistance - in the beginning, with the same temperature. If it it takes more current it is getting warmer then the longer one according U²/R. This would increase its resistance and the current will be decreased. In the end, there should be an automatic adapted distribution, some kind of balancing in the two wires - if the length difference is not too big. This PTC mimic should equally distribute the dissipated power per length, as can be seen in many heating devices with parallel wires like toasters, hairdryers, heating fans etc.